# Quickblox APNS certificate status change to inactive issue

Tags: ios, ssl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, quickblox

[image]

My Quickblox APNS certificate working fine  already in development mode.
Now i am turns to production mode for that i have uploaded 2 APNS certificate for that.
1 for development APNS and Production APNS as quickblox guide line.
After uploading show active both.
But some time later it goes inactive state and push notification stop working.
In setting tab show this

```
Development certificate #S3179-C1955
Valid till:  2015-08-22 10:16:33 UTC 
Status:  temporarily inactive

Production certificate #S3180-C1956
Valid till:  2015-08-22 10:16:33 UTC 
Status:  temporarily inactive
```

I am looking reason  for inactive state of certificate but getting solution for this. 
Any idea what wrong with that certificate?

Help me for that.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Please, share your error log of certificates.

Comment: @Olegykz error is: 2014-09-06 06:51:31 UTC: Connection reset by APNS: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A: sslv3 alert certificate unknown